# SerialPort names in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

The below code is the VC++ code to obtain the serial port names :

```
var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

The task is to find the equivalent VC++ code in Win32console Application.Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: You'll have to use RegOpenKeyEx and RegEnumValue to read the registry, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM key.

Answer (score 0):

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/293273/Ready-to-use-serial-port-enumeration-list-box) has both source code and explanation you want.